# List of existing tags in Mavericks

Tags: macos, tags, osx-mavericks

I'm trying to determine how to (quickly) generate a list of pre-existing tags in OS/X Mavericks (10.9). I can use Spotlight to list out all tags on all files and then sort for uniques but it's nowhere near immediate. The OS/X Finder clearly has access to the list of all existing tags, I'm curious where that list is coming from and whether I can also query the source.